# NEW TO UBUNTU, No loggin or password!

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, login, password

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.4 and I can only sign in as guest. I entered the User and Password I originally chose and nothing works. I can't do anything because I don't know the root password either. I run Ubuntu as well as Windows 7 Home Premium on my compaq. I'm brand new to Ubuntu and not too smart when it comes to coding. Please help if you can. And I'm not able to access the internet due to the fact I don't have the root password!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What do you *think* your username is? It will be generated for you based on your full name in the installation and it is all lowercase, a single word and without any whitespace. It is *not* your full name you entered yourself. And are you listed in the users in the login screen?

Comment: @hbdgaf This one is better to dupe against: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/88802)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password <br>

agreed.

Comment: Fair, but I can't take the dupe vote back.  It's definitely a dupe of something already on site about password reset/recovery.

Comment: @hbdgaf You can (since recently): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/167514#comment582472_915

Comment: I don't see an undo button, so unless I introduce a superfluous ninja edit, I don't think that meta applies.

Comment: I do have a retract close vote option, but I get a warning that I can't vote again after I retract.  It should be closed, So, I won't unvote, but I do recognize the merit of closing against something else.